# How to convert short date formatted string to NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, nsdate

I have a string containing date in a short date format, which i would like to convert to NSDate. What I tried is as follows

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:text];
```

The date object is nil always, not sure if i am specifying the date format wrong , or is it not at all possible to convert such string to date ? The string is in following format

> Fri Sep 4, 2015 10am

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: `MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a` and `Fri Sep 4, 2015 10am` are differ from each other thats why you are getting nil.

Comment: I would suggest a function that gives you a number for month.  NSDate isn't going to give you the exact day (such as Fri).  Once you have the month as a number it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM d,yyyy hha"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Fri Sep 4, 2015 10am"];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM d,yyyy hha"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Fri Sep 4,2015 10am"];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString *shortDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```